# Redux does not update the view after the reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

**SOLVED**: defaultValue in fields form is not what I thought it was.

I don't know what I'm doing [chemistry dog picture here].

My component is called *loadForm* and loads data from an API call through a thunk action:

```
class loadForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
  }
  /*  Loads data to the form */
  componentDidMount() {
    let action = getAppoThunk(this.props.routeParams.id);
    this.props.dispatch(action);
    console.log('DidMount  appoArray>>'+ JSON.stringify(this.props.appo));
 }

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (Object.keys(nextProps.appoArrayProp).length  !=  Object.keys(this.props.appoArrayProp).length ) {
  console.log('WWWW  NOT THE SAME nextProps  >>'+ JSON.stringify(nextProps.appo));
  console.log('WWWW  NOT THE SAME thisProps  >>' + JSON.stringify(this.props.appo));
  let action = getAppoThunk(this.props.routeParams.id);
  this.props.dispatch(action);  // thunk middleware dispatch
} else {
  console.log('ARE THE SAME this.props.appo>>' + JSON.stringify(this.props.appo));
}
```

}

the render:

```
   return(
     <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <label htmlFor="for_owner">Eingentümer (owner):</label>
      <input name="owner" defaultValue={this.props.appo.owner} />
    </form>
  );
```

**this.props.appo** is actually updated but the view doesn't change:

[image]

**UPDATE**

Thanks a lot guys for your help, since the beginning my reducer was:

```
    case RECEIVE_ONE_APPO
        Object.assign({}, state, {
         appArrayPop: action.appArrayPop
      });
```

In order to reduce complexity, I removed the array option replacing it with a simple string and, also, I deleted all the other reducers so my reducer now is just:

```
  const initialState = {
      eigentumer:  'initial'  // owner 
   };

  const appo_rdcer = (state = initialState, action) => { 
     switch (action.type){
      case RECEIVE_ONE_APPO:
         return Object.assign({}, state, {
            eigentumer: action.eigentumer
          });
```

Then I notice something weird:

```
return (
    <div id="responsive" className="modal hide fade" tabIndex="-1" >
      <Modal aria-labelledby='modal-label'
        style={modalStyle}
        backdropStyle={backdropStyle}
        show={this.state.showModal}
      >
      <Modal.Header>
         <Modal.Title>Modal Überschrift 1 --> {this.props.eigentumer}  </Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <label htmlFor="for_owner">Eigentümer: 2 --> {this.props.eigentumer} </label>
            <input className="form-control" id="for_owner" name="owner" defaultValue={this.props.eigentumer} />
        </form>
      </Modal.Body>
      <Modal.Footer>
         <Button onClick={() => browserHistory.push('/appointments')}>Close</Button>
         <Button bsStyle="primary">Änderungen speichern</Button>
      </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal>
  </div>
  );
```

Result:

[image]

So, **{this.props.eigentumer}** is updated in places 1 and 2 but not in 
*defaultValue={this.props.eigentumer}* and that is why the view is not updated. Now I need to [read this](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3357) to know why this is happening.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. A note on defaultValue though, this is the React way of saying "Populate this input on first render, but don't treat it as a dynamic value". If you use `value` instead, then you're good, but then you also need an `onChange` handler to tell React what to do when you write in the input field. Is the answer accepted then?

Comment: yeah, I changed to:

        <input placeholder="Owner" name="owner" value={this.state.owner} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'owner')} />

And I can handle all the onChange with a single method:

handleChange(name, event)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How do you change `appoArrayProp`? If you are working on the same object, and just removing or adding keys, `nextProps` and `this.props` are pointing to the same object, and these will in turn always be equal. Yes, it's not intuitive, but that's how it goes.

Let's say you have the object `appoArrayProp`:

```
appoArrayProp = {
  "foo": 1,
  "bar": 2
}
```

If you change it by simply adding or removing a property, `nextProps.appoArrayProp` and `this.props.appoArrayProp` will both point to the same object:

```
appoArrayProp = {
  "foo": 1,
  "bar": 2,
  "newProp": 3
}
```

and the Object.keys().length comparison will always return true. The solution is to create a new object, copying the properties of the current appoArrayProp, add or remove keys from the new object, then pass that on as a property:

```
appoArrayProp = Object.assign({}, appoArrayProp)
/* Do changes to appoArrayProp and render component */
```

Comment: Not intuitive, only if you didn't read any documentation at all. It's at the core of redux, immutable objects, you have to return new objects. Except for that minor beef, good guess considering the OP didn't show their reducer :p

Comment: nextProps.appoArrayProp  and this.props.appoArrayProp are pointing to the same object. It is important to handle Immutable principles. The reducer must return a new state object, not the same modified state. 

You can achieve it using Object.assign if you want to use native objects, or an external library as Immutable.js (this one is very usefull, but it generates extremely complex objects which are very difficult to inspect)

Comment: @JuanMendes We all make this mistake at least once :D

Comment: @dannyjolie I would hope at most once